# How to speed up left join queries by indexing?

Tags: mysql, indexing

At the moment I am experiencing some slower MySQL queries in my application which I want to speed up. Unfortunately I’m not quite sure which is the correct way to do it.

I have the following (fictitious) tables: `Book`, `Page` and `Word`.
`Word` is child of `Page` by `word_page_id`
`Page` is child of `Book` by `page_book id`

I already have individual indexes on `page_book_id`, `word_page_id`, `book_user_id` and `book_flag_delete`.

```
SELECT `book`.*, COUNT(word_id) AS `word_amount` FROM `book` 
LEFT JOIN `page` ON page_book_id = book_id 
LEFT JOIN `word` ON word_page_id = paragraph_id 
WHERE (book_user_id = 1) AND (book_flag_delete IS NULL) 
GROUP BY `book_id` 
ORDER BY `book_id` ASC LIMIT 100

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `book_id`) AS `book_row_count` FROM `book` 
LEFT JOIN `page` ON page_book_id = book_id 
LEFT JOIN `word` ON word_page_id = page_id 
WHERE (book_user_id = 59) AND (book_flag_delete IS NULL)
```

Any ideas how to speed up such queries?
Is there extra indexing involved?

Comment: Use  `explain select ...` to see which indexes are used and which you need to add

Comment: You probably don't need the joins in the second query, as you are selecting based on distinct book_id

Comment: Profiling queries and adding indexes is meaningless if MySQL can't utilize your server's hardware to its fullest potential. You assumed that by implementing "better" programming you will be able to solve a problem that has its roots in hardware as well. Even though you might get a good suggestion here, without tuning your MySQL - it will be to no avail. TL;DR: you need to tune your MySQL. Also, showing the table schema and output of `EXPLAIN` is required for proper help.

Comment: "individual indexes" tells me that you don't have any "composite" indexes?

Answer (score 4):

Set indexes on the fields you use for joining.

Further make sure that these have both the same datatype, encoding, and collation, else the index will also not be used.

`mysql> EXPLAIN <query>` will show you the actually used fields (`key` column in output) and the available indexes (`possible_keys` output field).

Comment: This answer took my 10+ second queries and turned them into 0.05 second queries.

Comment: Goddammit, I wasn't expecting different encoding and collation to make such a difference. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT b.*, COUNT(w.word_id) AS `word_amount`
FROM `book` b LEFT JOIN
     `page` p
     ON p.page_book_id = b.book_id LEFT JOIN
     `word` w
     ON w.word_page_id = p.paragraph_id 
WHERE (b.book_user_id = 1) AND (b.book_flag_delete IS NULL) 
GROUP BY b.`book_id` 
ORDER BY b.`book_id` ASC
LIMIT 100;
```

The best indexes are:  `book(user_id, book_flag_delete, book_id)`, `page(page_book_id, paragraph_id)`, and `word(word_page_id, word_id)`.

However, the overall group by might be expensive.  You might try writing the query as:

```
SELECT b.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(w.word_id) 
        FROM `page` p JOIN
             `word` w
             ON w.word_page_id = p.paragraph_id 
        WHERE p.page_book_id = b.book_id
       ) AS `word_amount`
FROM `book` b LEFT JOIN         
WHERE (b.book_user_id = 1) AND (b.book_flag_delete IS NULL) 
ORDER BY b.`book_id` ASC
LIMIT 100;
```

The same indexes indexes work here.  But, this query should avoid a group by on *all* the data at once (instead, it uses the indexes for the aggregation).

Answer (score 1):

The optimal schema for a many-to-many mapping table is

```
CREATE TABLE XtoY (
    # No surrogate id for this table
    x_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- For JOINing to one table
    y_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- For JOINing to the other table
    # Include other fields specific to the 'relation'
    PRIMARY KEY(x_id, y_id),            -- When starting with X
    INDEX      (y_id, x_id)             -- When starting with Y
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The details on 'why' are in [my index cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Answer (score -2):

In your select you're gonna want to refrain from using the wildcard "*" to grab columns. Plus utilize aliases ALWAYS!! This will keep your db from having to create a "virtual" alias.

```
select book1.column1, book1.column2, page1.column1 
from book book1 
left join page page1 
on page1.page_book_id = book1.book_id
..... blah
```

Comment: *virtual alias*? What is that?

Comment: Imagine your database has to remember which tables are being joined so it says okay I have table A and Table B. TABLE A? TABLE B?.column1? This is the test for ambiguity it has to do each time on each column. But when you have an alias it doesn't have to do that. It just checks if the column exists because you explicitly said which table using the Alias

Comment: Where did you get that from? Aliases are not needed. You only need them  if you join the same table twice or to name subqueries. You can use them for better readability. But thats it. They don't speed up anything!

Comment: You're asking for speed right? You are correct they aren't needed, in this case, but will slow down your fetch.

Comment: Aliases are highly desirable for many reasons.  Improving performance is not one of them.

Comment: Explanation of downvote - silly suggestion to avoid `SELECT *` and nonsense about "virtual" aliases, both of which have to do with performance as Jupiter has to do with a skateboard.

Comment: If you are going to use aliases, at least make them shorter do decrease the clutter, like Gordon's `b.` and `p.`.

Comment: **Upvoted.** Again, after getting my comments deleted continously without explanation or reasons. If you want to select all columns use Select * , if you don't want to select all columns, select specifically what you need. If you need 9 out of 10 columns, the best practices are to select those 9 manually. Performance does not come from fetching 1 column, it's calculated when fetching 1 column one million times a day.